# Node.js: How do I extract an embedded thumbnail from a jpg without loading the full jpg first?

Tags: node.js, image, jpeg

I'm creating a [Raspberry Pi Zero W](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/) security camera and am attempting to integrate motion detection using Node.js. Images are being taken with Pi camera module at 8 Megapixels (3280x2464 pixels, roughly 5MB per image).

On a Pi Zero, resources are limited, so loading an entire image from file to Node.js *may* limit how fast I can capture then evaluate large photographs. Surprisingly, I capture about two 8MB images per second in a background time lapse process and hope to continue to capture the largest sized images roughly once per second at least. One resource that *could* help with this is extracting the embedded thumbnail from the large image (thumbnail size customizable in [raspistill application](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md)).

Do you have thoughts on how I could quickly extract the thumbnail from a large image without loading the full image in Node.js? So far I've found a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349622/extract-thumbnail-from-jpeg-file). I'm guessing I would manage this through a buffer somehow?

Comment: I found a super fast option from [this blog](https://benjaminhorn.io/code/extracting-thumbnails-from-camera-raw-files-cr2-and-nef-with-php/). `exiv2 -ep1 -l /home/pi/ cam.jpg` very quickly extracts the thumbnail as its own image file (cam-preview1.jpg), faster than exiftools and anything else I could find (didn't find a node-specific option just yet). **If someone wants to wrap this in a promise-based answer that runs the process then loads it in using [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp), I'll give you the points.**