# Executing an exiftool command inside a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, exiftool

I found the following command line expression for exiftool here: [Extract thumbnail from jpeg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349622/extract-thumbnail-from-jpeg-file)

`exiftool -a -b -W %d%f_%t%-c.%s -preview:all YourFileOrDirectory`

The command works great on the command line, but when ran in the following batch program it seems the percent signs are misinterpreted and I'm not sure how to get it to be accept it. Can someone show me how to write this command for batch.

[image: This is the output:]

```
::  This exif command will create a file in the same directory as the one
::  where the original photo is located that contains all the thumbnail
::  images contained in the file's exif data. The exact path to the original
::  must be specified in this command.
cd\  
exiftool -a -b -W %d%f_%t%-c.%s -preview:all c:\users\cher\pictures\one.jpg
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [exiftool FAQ 27](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q27)

In a Windows .BAT file the "%" character is significant, so all "%" characters in ExifTool commands must be changed to "%%".

Comment: Works like a champ.  I know it's a weak question, but I didn't want to play around with the exiftool command just guessing and get something screwed up.  Thank you!